# Row is still clickable even after it has been clicked on

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I have made a row clickable within Jquery/Ajax as such :

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(function () { 
            $('tbody tr').live('hover', function () { 
                $(this).toggleClass('clickable'); 
            }).live('click', function () { 
                $.ajax( 
                            { 
                                type: "POST", 
                                url: "/Projects/AllProjectsHeaderSR", 
                                data:{ projectCode: $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text(), 
                                        l_frompage: "SearchProjectsHeaderResultSR" 
                                     }, 
                                success: function (data) { 
                                        $('#container').html(data);  
                                                  $(this).unbind('click');  

                                } 
                            }); 
            }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

When the user clicks on a row, a HTTPPost Method gets called via Ajax. This method then calls a PartialView.

The problem is that this PartialView page, which displays a Table of data, still remains clickable

How can i set this back to unclickable when the Partial View is rendered ?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that your hover function chained with click event is bind to any tr in your html. `$('tbody tr').live('hover', function ()...`. You can put an `id` or `class` to your table where you want the event will fire to be specific, so that other tr will not be affected

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYyVS/1/) example

I hope your PartialView with `#container` id is not within the table where the event took place.